# Static components in Dagger 2

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I'm currently learning `Dagger 2`. My Application class was starting to get cluttered, so I decided to set up a MainInjector class. It is supposed to handle component creation, and provide them to the requesting objects.

**Is it OK to keep some of my non-app-wide components static (eg. UserComponent)?**

Comment: Static components are hardly ever ok... Dependency injection help us to avoid it

Comment: @bigdestroyer so something like this is discouraged? https://github.com/svenjacobs/dagger2-android-template/blob/master/example/src/main/java/com/svenjacobs/dagger/example/inject/InjectHelper.java